# Why does Javascript WebSockets fail where Python's works?

Tags: javascript, python, websocket

I'm trying the following:

```
import asyncio, websockets
async def hello():
    uri = "ws://relay.magic-wormhole.io:4000/v1"
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as ws:
        # side is side1
        name = json.dumps({'type':'bind', "appid": "*/test", 'side':'312314a'})
        await ws.send(name)
        print(f"> {name}")
        greeting = await ws.recv()
        print(f"< {greeting}")
```

which prints

```
> {"type": "bind", "appid": "*/test", "side": "312314b"}
< {"welcome": {}, "type": "welcome", "server_tx": 1606663880.1907156}
```

I'm now trying the equivalent in my Google Chrome console and getting the following:

```
ws = new WebSocket("ws://relay.magic-wormhole.io:4000/v1")
WebSocket {url: "ws://relay.magic-wormhole.io:4000/v1", readyState: 0, bufferedAmount: 0, onopen: null, onerror: null, …}
VM272:1 WebSocket connection to 'ws://relay.magic-wormhole.io:4000/v1' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
```

Any ideas about how I can make the Javascript version connect successfully?

Comment: Its because you are trying to connect from another location. Open `http://relay.magic-wormhole.io` then try to do the same in the console and see if it works.

Comment: That makes sense and it works from that page. I was working from about:blank. Is there any way to allow a 'cross-site' websocket?

Comment: Do you have access to the server? What is the backend Node.js or..?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the server, which is running a python application...